# Make a number Fouriest

Tags: code-golf

The problem is taken from this comic: http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2874

[image: comic]

Your program must convert a number to the smallest base system in which it has the most fours in its digit sequence. Shortest code wins!

Function entries are allowed provided that the function prints the base in which the number is fouriest as well as the number in that base. You could just have it print "base:number" or "base number", so "5:4444" or "5 4444", or whatever is most convinient. Please provide sample outputs of your function when called.

Comment: What is the range of the bases? How small should they be?

Comment: Are function entries allowed? Must we output the number converted to base **n**, or may we output **n** instead?

Comment: Test cases would be a good idea.